# Map array elements to hash values Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash here,

```
    @property_hash = {
    :code => '',
    :fname => '',
    :lname => '',
    :basic_sal => '',
    :emp_type => '',
}
```

and an array

```
line = [02,'Firstname', 'LastName', 5800, 'PL']
```

I want to map the array into the hash like

```
@property_hash = {
        :code => 02,
        :fname => 'Firstname',
        :lname => 'LastName',
        :basic_sal => 5800,
        :emp_type => 'PL',
    }
```

what is the best way to do this ??
  Thank you

Comment: Can we assume `line`'s order is the same as `@property_hash`?

Comment: In future, consider waiting longer before selecting an answer. Quick selections can discourage other answers and, imo, are discourteous to those still preparing answers (not me). Moreover, the selected answer is sometimes shown to be incorrect (not here). Many here wait at least a couple of hours before awarding the greenie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
 @property_hash.each_with_index {|(k, v), index| @property_hash[k] = line[index]}
```

Not best way but that will work

Comment: Upvote because this changes the hash in place, which is more efficient than setting  `@property_hash` to a newly-constructed hash. Please remove your last sentence (which is akin to "I'm sure you'll say 'no', but would you go to the dance with me?").

Answer (score 2):

My solution assumes that line has the same order every time. So I define another array with the field names, merge the corresponding array elements together and convert the result into a hash.

```
line = [02, 'Firstname', 'LastName', 5800, 'PL']
fields = @property_hash.keys
# => [:code, :fname, :lname, :basic_sal, :emp_type]    


key_value_pairs = fields.zip(line)
# => [[:code, 2], [:fname, "Firstname"], [:lname, "LastName"], [:basic_sal, 5800], [:emp_type, "PL"]]

@property_hash = Hash[key_value_pairs]
# => {:code=>2, :fname=>"Firstname", :lname=>"LastName", :basic_sal=>5800, :emp_type=>"PL"}
```

Comment: As of Ruby 1.9 and onwards, hash entries are ordered by order of creation, so you can now rely on the order being present and consistent.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn: Thanks for the helpful information. I will edit my answer.

Comment: `fields` can be written as `@property_hash.keys`

Comment: @WandMaker: Yes, you're right. With the information of SteveTurczyn I can do so.

Answer (score 1):

Memory-wise, it is more efficient to change `@property_hash` in place rather than setting `@property_hash` equal to a newly-constructed hash. Here is one way to that:

```
lc = line.dup
@property_hash.update(@property_hash) { lc.shift }
  #=> { :code => 02,
        :fname => 'Firstname',
        :lname => 'LastName',
        :basic_sal => 5800,
        :emp_type => 'PL' }
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block to determine the value of keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which here is all of the keys.

Comment: Nice trick, not sure whether it will be used in real life like this

Comment: @Wand, that was my impression when I first saw it, but I've come to rather like it. For one, it returns the updated hash, unlike, for example, `h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = lc.shift }`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more way it can be done:

```
[@property_hash.keys, line].transpose.to_h
```

Comment: More generally, when arrays `a` and `b` are the same size, `a.zip(b)` and `[a,b].transpose` are interchangeable.